# Cannot convert to map when re-use one feature on other directory

Tags: karate

I have read: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5Dcannot+convert+to+map and https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/544

I am using karate-0.8.0

I have one feature which will be re-used on A directory, the content like:

```
@ignore
Feature:

  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * def Sign = Java.type('cruiser.token.Sign')
    * configure afterScenario =
    """
    function() {
      if (karate.info.errorMessage != null) {
        karate.log(karate.info.errorMessage);
      }
    }
    """
  Scenario:
    * def ck = Sign.execute('#(uid)')
    * path '/rest/n/rt/upload'
    * cookies ck
    * multipart fields  '#(fo)'
    * multipart file rt = { read: 'classpath:cruiser/http/rt/A/123.mp3', filename: '123.mp3', contentType: 'audio/mp3' }
    * method post
    * status 200
    * match response contains { result: 1 }
```

And have other one feature file on B directory, content like this:

```
Feature:
Background:
  Scenario:
    * def fo =
    """
    {
      'title': '你好！',
      'description': '很好听哦'
    }
    """
    * def x = call read('classpath:cruiser/http/rt/A/upload-base.feature') { uid: 33, fo: '#(fo)' }
    * match x.response contains { result: 1 }
    * print x.response.feed.id
```

its runner name is XRunner.java

when `mvn test -Dtest=XRunner`, the error info:

```
Running cruiser.http.rt.B.XRunner
11:25:33.138 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate - Karate version: 0.8.0
11:25:33.896 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - feature call failed: classpath:cruiser/http/rt/A/upload-base.feature
arg: {uid=33, fo={title=你好！, description=很好听哦}}

cannot convert to map:  '#(fo)'
Failed scenarios:
cruiser/http/rt/B/x.feature:3 # Scenario:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both these lines are wrong:

```
* def ck = Sign.execute('#(uid)')
* multipart fields  '#(fo)'
```

Read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

In Karate, expressions are pure JS by default. So just do this:

```
* def ck = Sign.execute(uid)
* multipart fields fo
```